# php regex for t.me links

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a regex php code to detect links like:

```
t.me/joinchat/AAAAAEEYZxAYyxhdag6z6g
```

I've tried :

```
$String = preg_replace("/[t.me][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/", "", $String);
```

I need to use `preg_replace` but the code above not working :(

What should i do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your link structure this regex could work:

```
t\.me\/[-a-zA-Z0-9.]+(\/\S*)?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wEvuBu/1

Your regex `[t.me]` is allowing a single character, with the options being `t`, `.`, `m`, or `e`. You also were missing the `/` after the domain which also would have caused a failure (your alphanumerical/hyphen character class would have allowed for the domain and directories to be found if `/` were added).